# How can I report logged task time by user and day in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, devops

Our company has recently began using Azure DevOps.  This morning I could not recall if I had entered my hours for yesterday towards a task.  I found the canned queries that are provided, but none of them show hours entered by day (date).

Is there a report/query in Azure DevOps that provides (at the user level) hours you have entered by DAY and TASK.

**NOTE**:  In our ENV, we do not have multiple people reporting time on the same task, so if we could get hours per day and task, we could assume the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure DevOps doesn't track user time at that granularity.  There isn't a built in report for it, and it would be difficult because it is only tracking an aggregate number, so if multiple users are entering time to a task, you wouldn't be able to see that detail easily.

In the past, I have used a marketplace extension, [Timetracker by 7pace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Berichthaus.TfsTimetracker#pricing), when I had the same time tracking requirements.  **Note:**  It does have a per-user monthly license.

Since you are fine about not having multiple people submitting time against a single task and instead have only one person tracking time per task, you can mock up something for the work items you care about using the [Revisions API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/revisions/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0).  Just grab the max revision for each day and print out the Completed/Remaining time and assume it is for the assigned-to user for the task.

Answer (score 6):

Now there is free [Time Logging Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TimeLog.time-logging-extension&ssr=false#overview).